# InDesign: How do I unlock a text box?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

I accidentally locked a text box, and now I can’t move it or edit the text. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> is probably what locked it in the first place. But how do I unlock it?

Answer (score 2):

Just click the padlock icon at the top left corner of the locked text box and it’s unlocked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, click the padlock icon, or hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> which is a shortcut to unlock everything on the current page or spread.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can also look on the layers panel, find the text box with a padlock icon next to it and unlock it from there.